# With Postgres, how can I use UPDATE to insert a new jsonb value if NULL, or amend the json if a value already exists?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a table in Postgres (version 10) that contains a nullable jsonb column:

```
CREATE TABLE j_play (
id                  serial PRIMARY KEY,
created_ts          TIMESTAMPTZ,
data                JSONB
);
```

It is possible that records may initially be inserted with no json data, and so the column will be null.

```
| id | created_ts                   | data
| 1  | 2020-09-11 18:18:37.47755+00 | [null]
```

I want to update this record so that if 'null' a json object is added, and if a json object already exists then it is amended.

```
UPDATE j_play SET data = '{"a": "12345"}'
| id | created_ts                   | data
| 1  | 2020-09-11 18:18:37.47755+00 | {"a": "12345"}

UPDATE j_play SET data = '{"b": "54321"}'   -- This is obviously bogus but the intention is to amend existing json
| id | created_ts                   | data
| 1  | 2020-09-11 18:18:37.47755+00 | {"a": "12345", "b": "54321"}
```

If the record starts with an empty json document then I can use jsonb_set:

```
| id | created_ts                   | data
| 1  | 2020-09-11 18:18:37.47755+00 | {}
UPDATE j_play SET data = jsonb_set(rec_data, '{a}', '"12345"', TRUE) WHERE id = 1
```

But I can't work out how to do this when the initial value is NULL. I can probably live with initialising the column to {} but I wondered if there was an elegant way to update it from NULL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to update this record so that if 'null' a json object is added, and if a json object already exists then it is amended.

Use `coalesce()`:

```
update j_play set data = coalesce(data, '{}') || '{"a": "12345"}';
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2532c5cc1c3eb1fd8b02004574f78e32)**:

```
insert into j_play (data) values(null);

update j_play set data = coalesce(data, '{}') || '{"a": "12345"}';
update j_play set data = coalesce(data, '{}') || '{"b": "54321"}';

select * from j_play;
```

```
id | created_ts | data                        
-: | :--------- | :---------------------------
 1 | null       | {"a": "12345", "b": "54321"}
```

Comment: That is beautiful, thank you! I was slightly aggrieved you answered so quickly and kept me up another 10 minutes, but that works perfectly and is indeed elegant. Now I might even sleep! ;-p

Comment: thanks! work fine................. But i dont understand, what is the objective that  jsonb_set not work when field jsonb is null? exists any reason?

Comment: My goodness this was driving me crazy. I don't understand why jsonb_set doesn't create it if set to true.