# Interpolating variables in json string

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am using the code below to create a function with variables that updates a jsonb column with a json object or create it if it doesn't exist -  [With help from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854471/with-postgres-how-can-i-use-update-to-insert-a-new-jsonb-value-if-null-or-amen)

However I am really having trouble interpolating the variables $2 and $3 in the json string. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.updateoffset(site text, offsetnumber integer, toscrape integer)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$


 update settings set "offset" = coalesce("offset", '{}') || '{"$2": {"toscrape":3$}}'
  where site = $1;
$function$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [format().](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

```sql
...
  update settings
  set "offset" = 
    coalesce("offset", '{}') || format('{"%s": {"toscrape":%s}}', $2, $3)::jsonb
  where site = $1;
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use string interpolation for building JSON values - use [JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) instead, particularly `json_build_object`:

```
update settings
set "offset" = coalesce("offset", '{}') || json_build_object($2, json_build_object('toscrape', $3))
where site = $1;
```

Also it might be simpler to use `json_set`:

```
update settings
set "offset" = json_set(coalesce("offset", '{}'), ARRAY[$2::text,'toscrape'], $3)
where site = $1;
```

(which, however, does keep other properties in the inner object, not replacing it completely with an object that has only `toscrape` as a key)

Comment: *Do not use string interpolation for building JSON values -* because?

Comment: @klin Because it doesn't do proper JSON syntax escaping and is basically an injection vector. Admittedly, not a problem in this particular context where `$2` and `$3` are known to be integers, but it could cause errors and possibly even security problems in general. So I recommend doing it the proper way even when it doesn't matter (and especially when the audience is oblivious to the problem), just to get in the habit - same as we do to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: @klin If an attacker controls the value of `$3`, and puts something like `'null}, "storeTarget": "attacker.com", "":{'` in there, they write the value of `"offset"->'storeTarget'` which was not intended by the programmer.